# Как получить названия списка валют из XML?

Tags: python, xml, парсер

Пытаюсь вытащить список валют по дате и поместить его в QComboBox (values), чтобы затем её отобразить курс в Label

```
with urlopen("https://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=%s/%s/%s" % (day, month, year), timeout=20) as r:            
            self.values.addItems(ET.parse(r).findall(    
                './/Name'))


<Valute ID="R01010">
 <NumCode>036</NumCode>
 <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
 <Nominal>1</Nominal>
 <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
 <Value>40,7014</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01020A">
 <NumCode>944</NumCode>
 <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
 <Nominal>1</Nominal>
 <Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name>
 <Value>48,7640</Value>
</Valute>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
from copy import copy

def dictify(r,root=True):
    if root:
        return {r.tag : dictify(r, False)}
    d=copy(r.attrib)
    if r.text:
        d["text"]=r.text
    for x in r.findall("./*"):
        if x.tag not in d:
            d[x.tag]=[]
        d[x.tag].append(dictify(x,False))
    return d

r = requests.get('https://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp')
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
d = dictify(root)
print(d) #словарь всех валют

print(d['ValCurs']['Valute'][0])#словарь только одной валюты
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = '''
<Valute ID="R01010">
 <NumCode>036</NumCode>
 <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
 <Nominal>1</Nominal>
 <Name>Австралийский доллар</Name>
 <Value>40,7014</Value>
</Valute>
'''

import xmltodict
print(xmltodict.parse(A))
# OrderedDict([('Valute', OrderedDict([('@ID', 'R01010'), ('NumCode', '036'), ('CharCode', 'AUD'), ('Nominal', '1'), ('Name', 'Австралийский доллар'), ('Value', '40,7014')]))])
```