# Поиск и вывод информации request

Tags: python-3.x, json, xml, requests

Написать функцию, принимающую в качестве аргумента код валюты (CAD,EUR,DKK ...) и возвращающую курс этой валюты по отношению к рублю.В качестве API использовать http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp

Как мне с этого злосчастного XML выдернуть нужную информацию?

Comment: На такой общий вопрос можно дать общий ответ. С помощью библиотек xml.etree.ElementTree, BeautifulSoup или lxml

Comment: другие дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1187072/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1028919/178576)